# Commit and push changes to GIT and upload changed files into external server

Tags: git, version-control, ftp, filezilla, uploading

What do I need to create script that allows me to commit and push changes to GIT repository and then upload files directly from local folder to external server by calling function through terminal.

I am trying to become more efficient and I want to handle changes much more easily.

Currently I am committing and pushing changes to my private GIT repo and then dragging & dropping files from local folder to server using FileZilla. This is not okay anymore for me.

It should include some kind of version number, that I could refer later on and it should also only upload files that were committed and pushed.

PS. I am working pretty much alone on this project.

Comment: What's the external server? Is it a ftp server (can only access through `ftp://` or can also access through `http://` or `https://`)?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT `ftp://`

Comment: Did you upload files to FTP server by git-ftp successful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) to depoly files from local git repo to your FTP server.
Detail steps as below:

1. Download and install git-ftp.

   As the example to install for windows OS:

   [Download file](https://git-ftp.github.io/)  (such as `.zip`) -> unzip -> download curl (such as `.zip`) -> unzip -> (make sure [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) is installed ->) in `bin` folder of the Git installed directory (such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`) -> copy `git-ftp` into the `bin` folder -> open git bash under installed git directory (such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git`) -> execute `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/master/git-ftp > /bin/git-ftp` -> execute `chmod 755 /bin/git-ftp`.

   You can also refer the instruction [here](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

   Now the git-ftp is installed.
2. Add a folder  (such as `repo`) under the FTP directory to get the files from local repo.
3. Setup git-ftp for local git repo and deploy to FTP server.

   ```
   git config git-ftp.url ftp://ftp-server/repo
   git config git-ftp.user <username for login FTP server>
   git config git-ftp.password <password for login FTP server>
   git ftp init
   git ftp push
   ```

Now all the files and the log (record the sha-1 when pushed to ftp server) are deployed to FTP server.

[image]